# Does python's break function apply to all loops, or just the one that contains the function?

Tags: python, loops

So I want to make a program in python 3. I have a loop, and noticed that I wanted to put a break function `break` to exit an inner loop. I don't want to exit the outer loop however, and want to know what it does.
(I'm making hangman, the word guessing game. I also know my code currently sucks.)

```
while True:
  letter = input("Choose a letter! ").strip().lower()
  for i in myword: #myword is a random word generated earlier.
    if i == "letter":
      message = f"You found the letter {i}"
```

Can someone help explain what the break will do?
I changed it so that `break` doesn't have brackets.

Comment: Did you ... _try it_ and see what happens?

Comment: That's a good point. I should've tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the innermost loop. So if you placed a `break` within the *for* loop, such as,

```py
while True:
  letter = input("Choose a letter! ").strip().lower()
  for i in myword: #myword is a random word generated earlier.
    if i == "letter":
      message = f"You found the letter {i}"
      break
```

your *while* loop will still iterate.

A small **program** to demonstrate this could be:

```py
y = 0
while (y < 10):
    for i in range(10):
        print(y)
        y += 1
        if (y > 5):
            break
```

The program still spits out values 0 through 9 and continues the *while* loop even though we told it to break at `y > 5`. It only breaks from the *for* loop.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Sorry about the grammatical errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use break in Python in all the loops: while, for, and nested. If you are using it in nested loops, it will terminate the innermost loop where you have used it, and the control of the program will flow to the outer loop.

here is a small example

y = 0
while (y < 10):
for n in range(10):
print(y)
y += 1
if (y > 5):
break